# how to set value to textField through a delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

i have two view controllers, view controller and tableViewController.
ViewController contains a textField and a button. when the button in viewController is clicked, then TableViewController should start.

in TableViewController, there is a list contains 5 rows, each row contains a string value.

What I am trying to do is, hen the user chooses any row in the list in TableViewController, then ViewController scene should start and the value that the user chose should be displayed in the textfield in ViewController.

to achieve this task, I created a protocol in TableViewController with a required method called `valueChoosen: (NSString *) value`, and this method is implemented in ViewController, and then I set the value to the textField but, at run time the TextField is empty.

please have look at the code below, and let me know why the value passed to the required method of the protocol can not be set to the textfield, what I am doing wrong;

**TableViewController**:

```
#import "TableViewController.h"

@interface TableViewController ()

@property NSArray *tableData;

@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.tableData = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Android",
                  @"iOS",
                  @"swift",
                  @"objective-c",
                  @"openCV",nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return [self.tableData count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView    
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]   
initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   
reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpg"];

return cell;
}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:   
(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSLog(@"%@", [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindSegue" sender:NULL];

[self.delegate valueChoosen:[self.tableData   
objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

@end
```

**ViewController**:

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
 #import "TableViewController.h"

 @interface ViewController ()

 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField   
*textFieldDepartment;

 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton    
*buttonSelectFromTableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a   
nib.
}


 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


 -(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
 {

 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueToTableView"]) {
    //code

    TableViewController *table = segue.destinationViewController;
    table.delegate = self;
 }

 }

 -(void) valueChoosen: (NSString *) value {
[_textFieldDepartment setText:value];

 NSLog(@"value: %@", value);
}

@end
```

Comment: call the delegate method before you perform an unwind segue

Comment: @StasVolskiy I tried it but still the textfield is empty

Comment: what is listed in logs? delegate method called?

Comment: Add the Delegate in header file

Answer (score 0):

It maybe because you are setting the `textfield` text in the `viewController` which is not being displayed. Try assigning the value to a variable using the `delegate` function and call the `delegate` function before performing the unwind `segue`. And on the `viewController` try setting the textfield text as the variable whose value was set through delegate method from the `viewWillAppear` method.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

create the unwind action in the viewcontroller you want to unwind it.in your case it is ViewController

```
- (IBAction)unwindFromModalController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{}
```

[image]
**Step 2:**
[image][image]
Connect to the unwind Action

- Control drag from tableviewcell to the Exit sign.
- Select the Action you specified.
- Add the Identifier to unwind segue.

**Step3**

Trigger the segue

in your TableViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
self.selectedText = self.tableData[indexPath.row];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindSegue" sender:self];}
```

**Step 4:**

Pass Data

Unwind Action

```
- (IBAction)unwindFromModalController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{
if ([segue.sourceViewController isKindOfClass:[TableViewController class]]) {
    TableViewController *vc = segue.sourceViewController;
    if (vc.selectedText) {
        [_textFieldDepartment setText:vc.selectedText];}
   }
}
```

Comment: but I when I drag from the tableviewcontroller to the exit icon nothing appears, I can link the the first method you mentioned in yourasnwer to the exit button in tableviewcontroller?? any other siggestions

Comment: @user2121 drag from tableviewCell to the Exit icon.

Comment: yes..exactly as what I didi but the exit icon never highlighted not present any menu so I can choose the method

Comment: have you write the method  - (IBAction)unwindFromModalController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{}    in the ViewController

Comment: yes I did write the following method in ViewController  
- (IBAction)unwindFromTableViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue{

    NSLog(@"unwindFromModalController");
}